# Hot Categories / inventory checker

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

We were given this activity in school to find categories that has no more stocks. Hot categories should be unique and without repeating categories.

```
const items = [
        { id: 'tltry001', name: 'soap', stocks: 14, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'tltry002', name: 'shampoo', stocks: 8, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'tltry003', name: 'tissues', stocks: 0, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'gdgt001', name: 'phone', stocks: 0, category: 'gadgets' },
        { id: 'gdgt002', name: 'monitor', stocks: 0, category: 'gadgets' }
    ];
```

Here is my code so far. I am only getting one category and cannot display the 2nd category with 0 stocks.

```
function findHotCategories(items) {
    
     let ilen = items.length
     for(let i = 0; i < ilen; i++){
       if(items[i].stocks === 0){
         let newArr = items[i].category
            return [newArr]
       }
    }
  };
```

Comment: What does a `return` do? Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

You `return` in the loop so the function ends where it matches the first item.

You should return after the loop

```js
const items = [
        { id: 'tltry001', name: 'soap', stocks: 14, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'tltry002', name: 'shampoo', stocks: 8, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'tltry003', name: 'tissues', stocks: 0, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'gdgt001', name: 'phone', stocks: 0, category: 'gadgets' },
        { id: 'gdgt002', name: 'monitor', stocks: 0, category: 'gadgets' }
    ];

function findHotCategories(items) {
  let newArr = [];    
     let ilen = items.length
     for(let i = 0; i < ilen; i++){
       if(items[i].stocks === 0){
         newArr.push(items[i].category)
       }
    }
    return [...new Set(newArr)];
  }
  
console.log(findHotCategories(items));
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is giving repeating categories.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked you goal. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// dont forget to UpVoted (:

const items = [
        { id: 'tltry001', name: 'soap', stocks: 14, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'tltry002', name: 'shampoo', stocks: 8, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'tltry003', name: 'tissues', stocks: 0, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'gdgt001', name: 'phone', stocks: 0, category: 'gadgets' },
        { id: 'gdgt002', name: 'monitor', stocks: 0, category: 'gadgets' }
    ];

const emptyStocks = [];
for( let a in items ){ if( items[a].stocks < 1 ) emptyStocks.push(items[a]); }
console.log( emptyStocks );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```js
const items = [
        { id: 'tltry001', name: 'soap', stocks: 14, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'tltry002', name: 'shampoo', stocks: 8, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'tltry003', name: 'tissues', stocks: 0, category: 'toiletries' },
        { id: 'gdgt001', name: 'phone', stocks: 0, category: 'gadgets' },
        { id: 'gdgt002', name: 'monitor', stocks: 0, category: 'gadgets' }
    ];

const totalStocks = items.reduce((acc, prev) => {
    if (!acc[prev.category]) {
        return { ...acc, [prev.category]: prev.stocks }
    }
    return { ...acc, [prev.category]: acc[prev.category] + prev.stocks }
}, {})

const emptyStocks = Object.keys(totalStocks).filter(key => totalStocks[key] === 0)

console.log(emptyStocks)
```

Answer (score 0):

My short answer with using `filter` and `map` function.

```js
function findHotCategories(items) {
  const result = items.filter(e => e.stocks === 0).map(e => e.category);
  return [...new Set(result)];
}
```